# Error "There is already an open DataReader associated with this command which must be closed first"

Tags: c#

I already define a data reader and close that on another method, and now I am using data reader again in this method then this error occurred:

```
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select ttl - paid from std_data where Std_ID = '"+textBox1 .Text +"'", con);
SqlDataReader cr = cmd3.ExecuteReader();//error here

while (cr.Read())
{
    bal = Convert.ToInt32(cmd3.ExecuteScalar());
}
```

Comment: You arent closing anything..

Comment: `cmd3` has already been used to create a DataReader. You cannot use it as `cmd3.ExecuteScalar()`. Which doesn't make sense either. What are you trying to do? Also, are you diposing of those objects somewhere?

Comment: No... i am trying to pass value of the query  ` SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select ttl - paid from std_data where Std_ID = '"+textBox1 .Text +"'", con); `   to variable     `Bal`

Comment: What type is `bal`? You have a DataReader there. It's used to read records. Maybe, you want to return a DataTable? A DataSet? All the records at once?

Comment: This can happen if you execute a query while iterating over the results from another query. It is not clear from your example where this happens because the example is not complete.One thing that can cause this is lazy loading triggered when iterating over the results of some query. This can be easily solved by allowing MARS in your connection string. Add `MultipleActiveResultSets=true` to the provider part of your connection string (where Data Source, Initial Catalog, etc. are specified).

Comment: Also, what is this: `ttl - paid`? Moreover, you really must read the Docs about Command Parameters. It'll save your life.

Comment: `bal` is int type .. i want to pass the query result to `bal`

Comment: @RahulSharma, i already added it

Comment: @Jimi , they are field names , i am calculating differernce from two field

Comment: @RadhaKhare The using statement will ensure correct disposal of the object and freeing of resources. In your code try: `using (SqlDataReader cr= cmd3.ExecuteReader()) {//Your code goes here}`

Comment: You get error on 5th line not the 2nd I think.

You don't need ExecuteReader() in this scnerio. You can use 

bal = Convert.ToInt32(cmd3.ExecuteScalar());

directly without a loop

Comment: Actually you don't need datareader in this case....just use simple executescalar no need for data reader